# Help translating 他这个辣把控是不是那种干辣干辣的感觉你知道吗

Tags: translation

[image]

In a video the guy was eating 冒菜
I don't get what he's saying especially 把控 and 干辣干辣
他 might be a typo

edit: It's this vid at 4:50
https://weibo.com/5602073113/Lv6FkoOZE?layerid=4774137945915894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **把** was repeated twice (I think mainly because what they are eating is really hot)

1. **把控** is not commonly used, has a similar meaning and is interchangeable with 控制, which means "to control something in your way". e.g. 他把这个局势把控得挺好 (he controlled the situation well)
2. **干辣** is not commonly used as well, in the video, he wants to make a statement about the flavor of the spicy. As a native speaker, it only means it's **truly and only** hot. Often times you hear 香辣 used to describe the food is **a little spicy and smells good**, which is the opposite of 干辣.

Answer (score 3):

> 他这个辣把控

他 is the same as 他们. It says ***the way they handle spicy taste.***

干辣干辣的 is the adjective re duplication. 干辣 could mean ***drily hot*** or ***purely hot***.

Comment: 干辣 could mean **simple spicy taste** when you eat dry pepper directly (without cooking). In this dish, they/chef must have put some 油辣子 in it, plus some other flavour, together, it will produce yummy spicy taste (不是那种干辣干辣的感觉).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be auto-translation of voice, which is not very precise.

他 should be它, which refers to 冒菜, and the first sentence should be "它这个辣吧",
which means "this spicy taste of this dish"

As for the second sentence, I don't really get it, it seems to be a mistake.
I think it's trying to convey "它不是那种干辣干辣的感觉你知道吗",
which means "it's not some dish that gives you the feeling of dry spicy, you get it?"

干辣 means drily spicy, I believe it's a spicy feeling that stimulates your throat and makes you cough